# Parallelizing query execution with Memgraph C++ Client

Tags: memgraphdb

I inherited a project that requires efficient data handling and query execution. I'm interested in optimizing performance and I'd like to know about the feasibility of parallelizing query execution using the Memgraph C++ client.

Is it possible to execute multiple queries in parallel directly through the Memgraph C++ client? If it can be done, what is the recommended approach to implement this? Are there specific patterns to follow (e.g., managing connections, handling concurrency, etc.)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `mgclient` doesn't expose specific parallelization primitives (every instantiated client/connection is separated, independent, and synchronous). Despite that i t's possible to execute queries in parallel by instantiating the client (example can be found at [basic.cpp](https://github.com/memgraph/mgclient/blob/master/examples/basic.cpp) file) inside multiple C++ threads. Basic parallelization should be possible in a reasonably simple way.